# Project that depends on a header only library, which depends on a header only library

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2017 to make a solution that contains two projects:

- project A: is a header-only library, that depends on Armadillo (a header only library)
- Project B: Just a main.cpp file that calls functions from Project A.

When I compile the project B, I am getting compilation errors on Armadillo. And I know there are no errors on armadillo, so I suspect that I am configuring something wrong, but I have no clue what.

The error I get is:

```
Error C2760 syntax error: token "identifier" where expected ";"
```

In the project B, I include the directories of the headers of project A, and Armadillo.

- Is, what I am trying to do possible?
- What can be the issue?

Comment: Can you make a [mcve]?  Sounds like you might have a file that is missing a `;` at the end of its last line.

Comment: ***Is, what I am trying to do possible?*** Of course. Nothing special should be needed to make this work.

Comment: ***I suspect that I am configuring something wrong, but I have no clue what*** Perhaps you are including something before the Armadillo header that is causing the issue. You will most likely have to track this down yourself. I suggest that you view the errors in the order that they appear in the Output Tab.

Comment: There are some additional options which can help to track down such issue: You can output all included headers by option (but, please, don't be shocked about the amount of output this will cause). 2. You can enable pre-processor output. This will provide the source code files after pre-processing. (Again, please, don't be shocked about the file size of resulting sources.) The pre-processed file (which contains all code instead of any `#include`) can be compiled again. Now, you can go back-wards from the error line to see exactly what was compiled before and might be the actual reason.